# Method to work out win/loss/tie and return points (football)

Tags: java, if-statement, methods

```
static final int WIN = 3;
    static final int TIE = 1;
    static final int LOSS = 0;


public static int berekenWedstrijdPunten(int[] mpUserTeamPunten, int[] mpTegenstanderTeamPunten){
        if (mpUserTeamPunten > mpTegenstanderTeamPunten){
            return WIN;
        }
        if (mpUserTeamPunten == mpTegenstanderTeamPunten){
            return TIE;
        }
        if (mpUserTeamPunten < mpTegenstanderTeamPunten) {
            return LOSS;
        }
    }
```

getting error lines under the if statements with > & <, trying to get a return of the win/tie/loss point into a print statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't compare two arrays with logical operators.